# May variable template variables vary?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Draft C++14 has added support for variable templates. The examples in the proposal ([N3651](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3651.pdf)) all show constants (either `constexpr` or `const`), but, from what I can tell, this is not required. May variable template variables vary, e.g., be assigned to?

```
template<typename T>
T magicVal = 42;

magicVal<int> = 0;       // okay?
```

Comment: As this is in the proposal state right now, it is hard to say.  Any attempt to say what will or won't be legal (or even if it will make the cut at all) at this point would be pure speculation.

Comment: The proposal was accepted, and the feature is in the current draft of C++14, so it's highly likely that this feature will be in the next version of C++. It's beyond the speculation phase.

Comment: @ZacHowland: The standard was more-or-less finalised earlier this year, and will only change if someone raises a serious objection in the final approval stages.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ah, I must have missed that ... I was holding out hope they would bring back `std::optional` ...

Comment: @ZacHowland It was killed by debate over interface design minutiae. Better to be sure about an interface that we will have to live with forever. Should come back in TR2, but I hope the interface to TR2 as a whole is more portable than TR1 was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, variable template instances are first-class objects. Effectively a template-id is just a name.

"Under the hood" a variable template just the same as an old-fashioned class template with a single `static` member.

**Edit:** It seems that the proposal was written in terms of `constexpr` constants only, such as to generically represent mathematical entities. Extension to other objects was requested by the reviewing committee and added as an afterthought.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a truly bizarre restriction; and reading through chapter 14 of the [latest draft](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf), there is no indication of anything of the kind.